# DNS server failover

Tags: domain-name-system, failover

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I automaticaly change the DNS A record to point my site to a secondary server in case of a failure?](https://serverfault.com/questions/6702/how-can-i-automaticaly-change-the-dns-a-record-to-point-my-site-to-a-secondary-se)

welcome
we have MS records for our domain in ISP DNS server and this records pointed to Main website hosted in ISP ,also we  hosted our web site in out of my location (in dedicated cloude) as backup web site,the question is:what is the best technique we can immplement in DNS server to switch automatically(without manually configured the DNS) to backup website(in dedicated cloude)if main server down??
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Answer:
[How can I automaticaly change the DNS A record to point my site to a secondary server in case of a failure?](https://serverfault.com/questions/6702/how-can-i-automaticaly-change-the-dns-a-record-to-point-my-site-to-a-secondary-se)